# Class not found despite composer dump autoload

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Good day,

I am getting a class not found error on our website.

```
Class 'BootForm' not found
```

However when I checked the vendor directory, the files are there.

So I ran this command.

```
php artisan version
```

The site that uses the same dependency was this version.

```
Laravel Framework 5.5.23
```

The site that is not working was this version.

```
Laravel Framework 5.4.35
```

And when I check the files, the working site had this file.

```
bootstrap/cache/packages.php
```

Does that mean that I have to update the laravel version?

Comment: Did you specify a valid `namespace`?

Comment: The error happens from the view. The view was working on the 5.5.23 version.

Comment: Are you using this lib https://github.com/dwightwatson/bootstrap-form?

Comment: in views use the class with full namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.5, a new feature was add called Package discovery

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/packages#package-discovery

In laravel 5.4 you have to add your providers array located in the `config/app.php` file

that''s why you got an error on your 5.4 version and not in the 5.5 one :)